# How to rectify no existing directory error in apiato project?

Tags: php, laravel

I developed some API's which is apiato project in that i developed some API's it's working fine  but when i run `php artisan optimize` command all my API's are not working i am getting following error

```
UnexpectedValueException: There is no existing directory at &quot;C:\apiato-project\apiato\storage\logs&quot; and it could not be created: Protocol error in file /home/vagrant/code/apiato/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 189
```

please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands:

```
php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple you just update the composer update

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

it will work